# How does the solenoid structure of $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$ lift to $PGL(2, \mathbb{A})/ PGL(2, \mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, p-adic-numbers

Some papers I am reading talk about an "adelic" object $PGL(2, \mathbb{Q}) \backslash PGL(2, \mathbb{A})$ .  This has sparked a lot of confusion since I don't know what such a quotient could mean.

A crude way of looking at the [adéles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106709/why-are-s-arithmetic-groups-interesting) is just as the product over primes:

$$ \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}_{p_1} \times \dots \times \mathbb{Q}_{p_k} \dots $$

Naively one might assume this passes over to groups of fractional linear transformations.  I believe the term is "strong approximation" though it doesn't make it any easier to understand.

$$ PGL(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}) = PGL(\mathbb{R}) \times PGL(\mathbb{Q}_{p_1}) \times \dots \times PGL(\mathbb{Q}_{p_k}) \dots $$

Actually even if we take just one part of that object the object is hard to understand, since $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is already a nasty object:

$$PGL(2, \mathbb{Q}) \backslash PGL(2, \mathbb{R})$$

I don't really understand what the rationals are doing here.  The only one I kind of understood is the identificaiton of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^3 = PGL(2, \mathbb{R}) \backslash PGL(2, \mathbb{C})$.  How to understand such a complicated group action?

---

It seems that for any two groups $H \subset G$ we could have $PGL(2, \mathbb{H} \backslash PGL(2, \mathbb{G})$.

- Kind of similar [References about $PGL(2,q^2)/PGL(2,q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425583/references-about-pgl2-q2-pgl2-q)

OK.  This object seems to be familiar to experts on automorphic forms - which I am definitely not:

- [Volume of PGL(2,F) \ PGL(2, A)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124529/volume-of-pgl2-f-pgl2-a)

---

**Partial progress** The issue of diagonal embedding $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{A}$ and the solenoid structure of $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$ are two major points that I missed.  The original question merely asked "What is $PGL(2, \mathbb{Q}) \backslash PGL(2, \mathbb{A})$?"

Although these points are in books, it would be great an outline of the "adèlic solenoid" structure of $PGL(2, \mathbb{Q}) \backslash PGL(2, \mathbb{A})$.

Comment: An easier question, which I think must be answered first, is: what is $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\mathbb{A}$? For answers, see e.g. this paper by A. Robert: 
http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?type=pdf&rid=ensmat-001:1974:20::62&subp=hires

You may also enjoy Weil's Basic number theory.

Comment: @AlainValette he says that $\mathbb{Q}$ is discrete in $\mathbb{A}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete insude $\mathbb{R}$.  Can you explain how the Adeles are "separating" the rationals?  OK is says it's a solenoid: $$ \mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q} \simeq \lim_\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{N} \mathbb{R}/N\mathbb{Z}$$
This limit must hold in a suitable topology?  I have no intuition what the "suitable" topology should be like, except formally.

Comment: Of course you know that $\mathbb Q$ is embedded *diagonally* here, right?  In this sense it is discrete because two 'real'ly close rationals have large denominators, so that there is some $\mathbb Q_p$ that sees them as being far apart.

Comment: Oh, also, the adèle (not adéle) ring $\mathbb A$ is significantly smaller than the full direct product $\mathbb R \times \prod_p \mathbb Q_p$, which would not be locally compact.  One takes instead the subring of those tuples $t$ for which, for almost all (i.e., all but finitely many) $p$, we have $t_p \in \mathbb Z_p$.  It may help in understanding the topology (or at least the discreteness of $\mathbb Q$) to see why this subring contains $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @johnmangual: The limit that you mention in your comment above is an inverse limit of topological groups, a standard construction. That is, the inverse limit has the structure of a topological group by definition. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711334/inverse-limit-of-an-inverse-system-of-topological-spaces

Comment: The "solenoid structure" you are asking about is addressed in the last sentence of my response. Briefly, $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ can be identified with the inverse limit of $\Gamma(N)\backslash\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, where $\Gamma(N)$ is the usual principal congruence subgroup modulo $N$.

Comment: Before considering $G(\mathbb Q)\backslash G(\mathbb A)$, consider $G(\mathbb Z[\frac12])\backslash G(\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q_2)$. Also, before $G=PGL_2$, consider $G=\mathbb G_a,\mathbb G_m,SL_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the quotient $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ and its generalizations for other (reductive) algebraic groups is a complicated object, and this is to a large extent the reason why the theory of automorphic forms is a deep subject. The diagonal embedding of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ into $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ connects the quasi-factors $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_v)$ in a subtle way, which otherwise would be completely independent. We would like to understand how much dependence is introduced and how much independence is lost by taking the quotient of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ by $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. This fits nicely in the general local-to-global philosophy of number theory.

By the way, one cannot just throw away some quasi-factors from $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ and take a quotient by $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, because the latter is meant to be embedded diagonally into $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$, i.e. it appears in every quasi-factor. Hence  $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ or even $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash \prod_{v\neq 2}\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_v)$, say, have little to do with the true adelic quotient $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$.

At any rate, there are good introductions to adelic quotients. I recommend Chapter IV in Weil: Basic number theory, especially Section 2 there which explains why the adeles are separating the rationals much like the reals are separating the integers. Then one can read Sections 3.3 and 3.6 in Bump: Automorphic forms and representations, which explains in the setting of $\mathrm{PGL}_2$ the connection of the adelic quotient to classical congruence quotients.

Comment: no I missed the part about diagonal embedding.  Does it look like this? $$ \prod_{\{-1\} \cup \text{primes}}\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$$

Comment: @johnmangual: What you write is not the adelic quotient. You have to divide the restricted product $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ instead of taking a restricted product of the local quotients (which are not even Hausdorff). Note also that $\mathbb{R}$ is usually denoted by $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}_{-1}$.

Comment: @johnmangual: For comparison, $\mathbb{R}^2$ divided by $\{(x,x):\ x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is very different from $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^2$. In the first case you get a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$.